# How to move focus out of tabulator table by navigating with keyboard?

Tags: javascript, angular, tabulator

I would like to move the focus on the first focusable element on a page placed after the table when focus was set on the last cell in the table and tab key was presed. Similarly, I would like to move focus on the first focusable element when focus was set on the first cell in a table and I pressed SHIFT+TAB.

It seems like Tabulator prevents the default tab behaviour when focus is set on the last or the previous cell in a table.  I found out that I can move out of table on the next focusable element after table by clicking ESC and then TAB, but still can't find a way to focus the first focusable element available placed before the table.

I illustrated my use case on the graphic below. Is it possible to achieve this navigation behaviour with Tabulator api?

[image]